# ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ora-00942

I am passing a select query from java, it works for all table but one of the table gets an error "ora-00942 table or view does not exist". I checked grant and all, its same for all table. But for some reason it complains abtout this particular table. But if I run the same query in sql plus it works completely fine. Can someone tell me what may be the reason behind it. Thank you

Comment: Post the code.  Is the schema correct?  Are you using a synonym?

Comment: Login as the Java user (J2USER perhaps?) and run the same query.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are using a different user from sqlplus than from your Java program, and then the error is caused by a missing synonym/schema name.